# Stale props / No re-render on child passed as prop

Tags: reactjs

I have seen similar questions but I am unable to solve this issue.

I am passing components or tabs as props that themselves have props. However, when these update (specificallly `soundsBeingPlayed`) the components do not update. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

```
const TABS = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        title: "Sounds",
        id: "sounds",
        component: (
          <Sounds
            soundsBeingPlayed={soundsBeingPlayed}
            onSoundPress={onSoundPress}
          />
        ),
      },
      {
        title: "Places",
        id: "places",
        component: (
          <Places
            onPlacePress={onPlacePress}
            soundsBeingPlayed={soundsBeingPlayed}
          />
        ),
      },
    ],
    [soundsBeingPlayed]
  )

render (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
       <Tabs tabs={TABS} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: @JBaczuk it's an array that gets updated by the parent component - so `Tabs` is just presentational.

Comment: Can you share a complete component that is reproducible? It depends on how the props are defined and updated.